# Jquery Hide Function in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a while statement that is echoing about 10 different stories. Every story has a user comment. When clicking the button edit I want one of the functions to hide the user comment. Here is the code I wrote to try and make it happen. Let me know if you think of why this wouldn't work.

```
<script>
    $(".edit_<?php echo $story_id ?>").click(function () {
    $(".comment_<?php echo $story_id ?>").hide("fast");
     });    
</script>
<?php
if (!empty($user_comment))
echo "
<p class='user_comment comment_$story_id'><strong>$user_comment</strong> <a class='edit_story_comment edit_$story_id'>Edit</a></p>";
else
echo "<p id='user_comment_$story_id'><span id='edit_no_story_comment'>Edit</span></p>";
?>
```

Comment: can you provide any more info? like whats happening or errors that are occuring, firebug errors etc

Comment: As a side note, the way you're implementing your jQuery is very inefficient and is going to go murderously slow on old browsers, as it will have to do a full DOM traversal to attach *each* event, and then another one every time the event is triggered.  There are several things to do to fix this, but the most simple is just to assign unique IDs instead of unique classes and look up using `$('#some-unique-id')` instead of `$('.some_class_name')`, as ID based lookups are fast.  Further improvements - use one handler for all with `delegate`/`live` and cache the lookup inside the callback.

Comment: It just wasn't hiding the user_comment. However the solution below fixed it.

Comment: El Yobo, I would have used ID's however you cannot assign multiple id's like you can with class. Example you can have class="class1 class2" but you cannot have id="id1 id2" - As far as my knowledge is concerned.

Comment: Great news your problems have been fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so im gonna ges its becuse of the ankertag is being defined after you are
hocking upp the event with jquery

use jquerys on load event to get around this

```
$(function() {
 $(".edit_<?php echo $story_id ?>").click(function () {
  $(".comment_<?php echo $story_id ?>").hide("fast");
 });    
});
```

hope this help

(mixing php html and jquery and string concatenation is beautiful btw :D)